# Translate it for me Vs. Translate it to me

Tags: prepositions, difference

What's the difference between these two sentences using two different prepositions?

> Translate it **for** me.

to

> Translate it **to** me.

Comment: Translate it "for me" is the standard. "to me" is not idiomatic to native English, even when the translator is speaking the translation.

Comment: @BruceMurray I'm tempted to say "to" _might_ work in a face-to-face scenario, in which the one tasked with translating is, e.g., being helped with practicing for an exam - but I'm uncertain, and that would be a fringe case.

Comment: @Wehage Yes, I agree, although "translate it back to me" sounds cleaner.